# can't install virtualenv on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, pip, sudo

i have to install virtualenv on ubuntu 12.04 but it shows following error

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
[sudo] password for raushan: 
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement virtualenv
No distributions at all found for virtualenv
Storing complete log in /home/raushan/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: try using pip --proxy <host:port>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/

It sounds like you're unable to access PyPi.

Try navigating to http://pypi.python.org/simple/ in your browser to see if you're able to connect. Do you use a proxy to access websites?

It may also be useful to check if you're able to access PyPi from the command line. Try:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

If you're using a proxy, enable that on the command line:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://your.proxy.address.com:8000"
export HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY
```

replacing your proxy address and the port with whichever details you have.

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem. and i use proxy. what need I do?

Comment: @DavidW. I've updated the answer to include proxy instructions.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to install it on ubuntu, then try this

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

This will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

it happens because of heavy load on http://pypi.python.org. other alternatives are the mirror site.download the package from mirror site like [mirror site](http://c.pypi.python.org.com) and use this command on terminal >> python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this Error as follow  while Yum Update or yum install :

```
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: fedora/18/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
```

Answer : 
  Please check your Proxies i.e env variables 1. **http_proxy** 2.  **https_proxy** 3. **http_proxy** in the */etc/yum.conf*

Enter the proxy like :

```
export http_proxy=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port_no
export https_proxy=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Python virtual environment called :
I have given it VE.

git clone https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv.git

python virtualenv.py VE

To Activate your new virtual environment, run:

. VE/bin/activate
Sample outputs (NOTE prompt changed):
(VE)c34299@a200dblr$

Delete the cloned repo afterwards.