# not able to install tensorflow on server

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow on my college server, as some of the things that I have written are too heavy for my laptop.
So I don't have sudo privileges. Below is what I unsuccessfully tried.

I am able to install tensorflow by `pip install --user <url>`
. But when I import tensorflow I get the error `glibc 2.17 not found`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f) link which solved the exact same problem but when I run

`virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow`

I get this error:

`ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

For resolving this I tried:

`wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python`

And then I get following error:

`[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-10463.write-test'`

And I don't have sudo access so I can't use sudo with above command.

For installing virtualenv I used:

`curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito/master/virtualenv-burrito.sh | $SHELL`

I think that the problem is with virtualenv setup but I tried removing it and installing virtualenv by:

`pip install --user virtualenv`

But this fails and I get:

`InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vitualenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for vitualenv`

I have looked at many ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331782/cant-install-virtualenv-on-ubuntu-12-04)) SO answers dealing with this problem but none work for me. I get stuck at some other error.

I am now stuck in a loop of errors without sudo privilege.

So, my question is that do I necessarily have to install virtualenv or can my problem of installing a working tensorflow be solved much simply.

It is a linux server and default python version is 2.6. So, I had to install 2.7 separately for my use.

Answer (score 2):

Try [building from source](http://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#installing_from_sources) instead of using the precompiled binary version.  That way you won't have to worry about the glibc incompatibility with the installed system one.

Comment: As tensorflow (google) uses bazel, I couldn't install this way too. When trying to install bazel it asks for some java packages that I don't have. Or can I install it without using bazel. I am a little new to this so I am not sure, but there documentation doesn't mention anything about installing without bazel.

Answer (score 0):

@Pukki you may be able to have a professor request the system administrator to install it. Then everyone on the system could use it.

Comment: Yes this is the conclusion I came to, too.

Comment: But this is not a technical solution. It is an administrative workaround.

Comment: @Pukki I assure that in the real world we also have to have administrative workarounds to get certain programming issues resolved.

Comment: I think installing Docker or the virtual environment would need the same permissions. How about making it a portable app. I was able to put these on my student shared directory at school. http://portableapps.com/

Comment: If pip is installed maybe you could use virtualenv. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md

Comment: @technologiclee  If you go through my question, you will find that I had already tried virtualenv. BTW I talked to a professor and had it installed. So, thanks.

Comment: Can you see TensorBoard when you run it from the server? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836728/view-tensorboard-on-docker-on-google-cloud

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions from [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation) and it resolved my issue. You need the `--upgrade URL`  parameter